# Tuxedo Client or Tuxedo Server

Tags: tuxedo

Here is my question and i tried it hard to brainstormed with people in my team and with other resources which i have.

I have to go 100's Linux black-boxes to find if Tuxedo Client is running there or not . How can i tell if Tuxedo Client is on each box.

Maybe Tuxedo Server is running on that box may its just installed and not running .How can i different between Then Tuxedo Client and Server.

Is there any procedure or way or any command which i can used and which can tell me if Tuxedo client is there on box or not.

Comment: I read the question several times and still didn't understand if you want to know if the tuxedo software is installed, or if the tuxedo processes are running. Also seems not clear whether these boxes are clients or servers.

Answer (score 2):

To check if a Tuxedo domain is running in a server, you could check if there is BBL process running.

```
# ps -ef | grep BBL
```

For clients, there are many ways that a Tuxedo client's may connect to servers:

Example:

via:

- /WS
- JOLT
- Direct connection
- Weblogic Tuxedo Connector (WTC)
- Server calling another tuxedo servers (via tdomain)

To verify tuxedo clients conecting via **WTC/JOLT** there must be a Weblogic Server OR Java process calling tuxedo servers.

```
# ps -ef | grep java
```

To verify tuxedo clients that connects via **/WS** there must be a WSNADDRR defined in the enviroment of the process.

```
# ps auxeww  |grep -i WSNADDR | grep -v grep
```